# create excel sheet in android

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am trying to generate excel reports from my android app and for that i came across `apache POI` but when i import the jar files into the folder its showing me following error whoich i have found at may places over web.

for libraries like

```
poi-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar

trouble writing output: Too many method references: 76142; max is 65536.
```

then i went down to the little later version

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 66024; max is 65536.

poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
```

i have seen may post related to it , but still didnt find any definate way to resolve the issue , would appreciate if anyone can suggest a roadmap

Comment: You need to reduce your dependencies, or enable minification in your debug builds, to reduce your method reference count.

Comment: and how would i do that , can you please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your libraries are defining a lot of methods you may not use.
Try enabling minify inside your gradle build file:

```
 android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }
```

This will stop compiling unused code.
[ProGuard](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard#) is included inside the AndroidStudio gradle plugin.

In addition you can enable [resource shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking):

```
...
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
...
```

*Same for `debug{...}`*

## Update

Looks like a build tools problem:
[Changelog](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html) BuildTools v21.1 (October 2014):

"*Added multidex file support for APKs and Jack suppport to address the 64K method reference limit.*"

Comment: as i using eclipse is any different way to do above procedure or should i shift it to android studio

Comment: I would highly recommend doing this. Android Studio is **official** now . It makes things a lot easier for me. Give it a try.
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: i have set everything and i am getting following error`I/O Error: C:\Users\bhatt\AndroidstudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Please paste your complete build.gradle[app] file here http://pastebin.com/ and comment the link.

Comment: Please update your build tools over the SDK Manager (We're on 21.1.2, you are on 19.1.0) also use compileSdkVersion 21

Then you do not specify the buildType "debug".

here is what i would try :
http://pastebin.com/fqrNqVF7

(I also edited the dependencies to automatically add all jar files inside the libs folder)

Also let AndroidStudio check for updates.
Extra information: 
Changelog BuildTools v21.1:
Added multidex file support for APKs and Jack suppport to address the 64K method reference limit.

Comment: while running app i am getting `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\bhatt\AndroidstudioProjects\InventoryAudit\app\proguard-rules.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: in the build file I've sent you, i wrote "proguard-rules.pro" , are you sure you copied it correctly ? ;)  http://pastebin.com/fqrNqVF7

Otherwise delete in the line after **getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')**